# Exception when creating PosExplorer object using Microsoft PointOfService namespace

Tags: c#, pos-for-.net

```
      PosExplorer myPosExplorer = new PosExplorer();
```

This keeps giving me a System.Typeinitilization exception. MSDN says "A NotSupportedException exception is thrown when an invoked method is not supported, or when there is an attempt to read, seek, or write to a stream that does not support the invoked functionality."

So apparently this class does not support its default constructor?

Help?

EDIT looking a little deeper, view details tells me that it inner exception is
" This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information."}"

I added

to my app.config file and it solved my issue hopefully it does not cause any others.

Comment: In the future if I resole the issue on my own should I remove the question or leave it in case someone else experiences a similar issue?

Comment: Leave the question, more overall learning is good. You can also post an answer with your edit, and mark the question as answered.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question You should answer your own question rather than providing the answer as an edit, and leave the question.